# Prove that the given entire function $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is an entire function and
$\kappa = \{a_1\alpha+a_2\beta \mid a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. whenever $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p\alpha + q\beta = 0 \implies p,q=0$

$f$ also satisfies $f(z + k) = f(z) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}, k \in \kappa$.

Need to show that $f$ is a constant function. I'm not sure how to proceed with this. Any help is appreciated.
P.S: I've recently started learning complex analysis.

Comment: have you seen Liouville's theorem yet? If so, it would suffice to show that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=i$. Your assumption is saying that if you know how $f$ is behaving on the ‘unit square’ with vertices at $0,1,1+i,i$, then you know it everywhere. Boundedness on this square is obvious. Why? So what? What about the more general case? What is the linear-algebraic name for the condition you’re given?

Comment: @user1090793 yeah I have come across the statement of Lioville's theorem, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case and conclude that $f$ is constant.

Comment: @TheLimitDoesNotExist: read the statement of the theorem again, paying particular attention to the hypotheses : ) By assumption, $f$ is entire. What is the other hypothesis?

Comment: @user1090793 I mean, yeah it follow's from the statement that if $f$ is entire and bounded, then it must be constant. I meant to say how should I go about showing boundedness with the "linearly independent" $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: @TheLimitDoesNotExist going back to peek-a-boo's comment, you should be able to use the linearly independent part to show that any point in $\mathbb{C}$ can be expressed as $z + k$ for some $z$ in the square that peek-a-boo describes, and some $k \in \kappa$. To think about this in linear algebra terms, consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo to show that $f$ is bounded, do I simply say that the unit square is compact in $\mathbb{C}$, and every entire function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded?

Comment: yes so it is bounded on the unit square. By the translation symmetries, it is thus bounded on all of $\Bbb{C}$, so...

Comment: Alright, then we are done with Liouville's theorem.